# What is the path to the title video in Windows ME?

Tags: windows

In the Windows Millennium Edition Preview, there is an intro video that appears to play in a Windows Media Player window. I've seen several YouTube videos that contain the video. What is the path to the video, or is there no path and those online videos are just screencasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the Windows ME Introduction Video? That's at `c:\windows\options\install\winme.wmv` Oddly, I don't recall ever seeing it until now. Maybe I've blocked the trauma of ME from my memory.